# Google Web Fonts Anti Aliasing Issue

Tags: css, fonts, google-webfonts

I am trying to use the Antic font found in Google Web Fonts. This is a beautiful font and my entire website was designed based around it.

I started coding my site, but I am having this annoying anti aliasing issue with Antic.

I tried everything in CSS...

```
font-smooth: always;

transform: rotate(-0.0000000001deg)

-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;

text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); <- barely works
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old and you're already passed this at this point, but for anyone else who comes searching...

If the problem is only webkit, then you may have some luck with your -webkit prefix, but I normally go without the subpixel. Like `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

That's not going to help when it comes to problems with IE and other, non-webkit browsers. For those, try reordering your webfonts with svg as the first option. Or you can try ommitting it altogether. This normally solves any problems I have had and if you can get away with it, try getting rid of the iefix as well as that can cause problems in ie10. If you can't try to move that one up the list as well if you're stuck supporting the older ie's.

Answer (score 0):

[How to apply font anti-alias effects in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864742/how-to-apply-font-anti-alias-effects-in-css/17886204#17886204)

```
    -webkit-text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.01) 0 0 1px;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```