# Clear text CSS solution

Tags: css, text, fonts

How get clear text, my text always have rough line my code is:

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
color: #444;
```

What i need to add for smooth clear text ?
I see on mobile phone text is clear but on pc, chrome text have this rough line,

Comment: Could we get a [demonstration](http://www.jsfiddle.net) of your issue?

Comment: I think, that is not css question. Hardware/settings?

Comment: I ask if in css exsist some code for make text clear, smooth or this is it ?

Comment: you could try the answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864742/how-to-apply-font-anti-alias-effects-in-css