# Issue with font rendering on chrome

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome

I am having issue with font rendering on Windows Chrome. I am using Google Lato font, size 10px with font weight 300. Here is the comparison between rendering on Mac and Windows:

Chrome Windows:

[image]

Chrome Mac:

[image]

As you can see, the font on Windows is very hard to read. I have tried to use:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

but it didn't worked. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lcj9yxuo/

Comment: Have you tried: `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility`

Comment: Just tried it. Didn't helped.

Comment: Can you create an snippet to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @DaniP, I added example.

Comment: From your fiddle, the problem I see is just a color difference

Answer (score 0):

you can add some text-shadow to your styling

```css
label{
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight:300;
  font-size:10px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.2) 0 0 1px;
  text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.2) 0 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,300italic,400italic,700italic&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<label>
gwarancja niskich cen
</label>
```

for more details and explanation see the source : [How to apply font anti-alias effects in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864742/how-to-apply-font-anti-alias-effects-in-css)

Comment: This didn't changed the rendering - it looks exaclty the same as it did without this style.