# Why do the browsers render center aligned text differently at different resolutions?

Tags: html, css

I have a "notification bell" on my website and a number in it (how many notifications you have). That number is in the middle until about 1200px, then it goes slightly to the left (1px).
Looking closely with Photoshop, the text becomes 1px smaller. How, and why is this happening?

Tested in Chrome.

**EDIT 4:** So this turned out to really be a rendering issue only. Nothing can be done by CSS.

**EDIT 3:** This is just getting weirder. I added display: inline-block after removing float, but it became wrong again. However removing float: left, and removing the menu option this is paired with, brings the issue back. Aww... :(

**EDIT 2:** it seems I found the cause. This is in the menu for me, and the menu items have float: left. I removed the float left (of course it's a mess now), but the number went exactly to the middle. No idea though why this doesn't happen at lower resolutions.

**EDIT: Added screenshot!** On the left, it's the smaller resolution, the "0" is in the middle, but on the right with bigger resolution it's 1px to the left. I know it's barely visible, but it annoys me.

[image: screenshot]

[image: good image till ~1200px]

[image: bad image at higher resolutions]

Some html:

```
<span class="open_notifs main notif"><span class="item">0</span></span>
```

Here's some CSS too:

```
#cs_menu span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
}

#cs_menu span.notif {
    background: url(/images/notif-bell.png) no-repeat;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 4px;
}

#cs_menu span.item {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: initial;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}
```

Comment: add screen shots of the browsers views... with the dev panel open showing the css.

Comment: looks like the zero in the lower picture is an odd amount of pixels and therefore the centring will be off to the left 1px where as the zero in the first picture is even so the centre can be directly in the middle.  Must be just the way the font renders for each resolution

Comment: @Pete I think the OP is trying to ask why the same character in the same size is displaying differently at higher resolutions. And "That's just the way it is" is not a very satisfying answer.

Comment: That's why it's a comment @MrLister if I had an answer I would have answered - might be better to ask that question on graphic design stack exchange where they have more understanding of fonts and rendering

Comment: I know it's just 1 px and probably 99% of the people don't care, yet it's driving me crazy, because I can see it.

Comment: @Seabizkit Added screenshot.

Comment: What about antialiasing the font: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864742/how-to-apply-font-anti-alias-effects-in-css maybe this is what you need?

Comment: @Zydnar Unfortunately that didn't help, but it seems I found the cause. This is in the menu for me, and the menu items have float: left. I removed the float left (of course it's a mess now), but the number went exactly to the middle. No idea though why this doesn't happen at lower resolutions.

Comment: @Jones consider posting it as an answer to your question

Comment: @Jones remove `text-shadow` from `#cs_menu span.item`

Comment: Well, I gave up, it's just 1px... If someone wants to play with it, it's at https://hearthstonehungary.hu - you have to register first (Hungarian)!

Answer (score 0):

I seen some issue in your `html` and `css` `code`. Your `CSS` is overwritten many times. `span` `tag` is conflict with `CSS` `code`. You can replace the notification `icon` and `text` between `div` and `span`. I use `flexbox` to `fix` this `issue`. Also you haven't write complete `code` for `background image`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="notificaiton-icon">
    <span>0<span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.notificaiton-icon{
  align-items: center;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-image: url(https://hearthstonehungary.hu//images/notif-bell.png);
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 36px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 30px;
}
.notificaiton-icon span{
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

[Here is the Pen](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/YzPjZpO).

> Note: use fresh `element` for this notification `icon` and `text` avoid to conflict `css` overwritten issue. Use `flexbox` it will help you to `center` `vertically` and `horizontally`.

Comment: Thanks for doing this. However this just proves that this is only a rendering issue. I made one modification in your code: I set the .main-container to 40px width: https://codepen.io/Phoenixy/pen/wvBxyQq - It's still good, but if I set it to 41px, it's bad: https://codepen.io/Phoenixy/pen/OJPwQam ... It's good at 42px, bad at 43px, good at 44, bad at 45, so on...